# Globally Accessible Log4Net variable

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I currently have the following setup in my application_start

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")));
```

now in order to then log out to log4net I need to add to every controller an instance;

```
public static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

as this is something I want to use throughout the api. Can I declare this in the global.asax so that I can then just call;

logger.Error("output");

whenever its needed?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want each class to have its *own* named logger (in which case you don't want to share the field at all) or do you want each class to use that one specific logger but without having to declare it (in which case you could have your controllers inherit from a base class)? In general, to minimize dependencies, I'd say have every class that wants to log actually declare its own logger as a private field. If you want to use the same logger everywhere, simply use the same name.

Comment: Sorry I want to simply add a global one which any class in the application can access?

Comment: @JeroenMostert so yes ideally I would like to be able to just call the logger anywhere. One I sea I had was to create a static log4nethelper class which I could just call using log4nethelper.log.error etc?

Comment: This is asp.net-mvc, right? You may want to add that to your question tags to get better responses. I know MVC has better solutions for logging than referencing a static field everywhere, but I have no experience myself.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn Do you want to use your Logger for Exception and Error logging or Do you have other requirements like logging custom messages? There are builtin option in WebAPI that you can use and extend to customize the Exception handling and logging.

Comment: @vendettamit I suppose this could work if I add an exception filter. Basically i need to log errors but I will also need to log entity framework generated sql as well. Any idea with the latter? Could an filter be used to do this?